# Navigation drawer hide the content of the extending activities

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I try to get a navigation drawer that can be used for every activity (in kotlin). Unfortunately the content of the activities isn't shown if I extend the NavigationDrawerActivity. I know there are a lot of questions about this topic but the already given answers couldn't fix my problem.

I toke the most from the Android Studio Navigation layout so my NavigationDrawerActivity looks like this:

```
abstract class NavigationDrawerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_layout)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        //Handle selected item
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
}
```

The belonging layoutfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".NavigationDrawerActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now when I create an activity extending the navigation the content of the layout of the activity (activity_main) isn't shown.

```
class MainActivity : NavigationDrawerActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

Maybe it's because of the order of the two statements in the MainActivity:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

But if I change the order I can see my content, but not the Navigation.

Does anybody know my error?

Comment: It's impossible to do it like that. You can't `setContentView()` twice and get merge effect

Comment: So it's wrong to have this call in both activities right? Do you know how I can change my code? Is the only way to work with fragments?

Comment: So I guess I have to include a FrameLayout to my layout file. Can anybody tell me how to work with that without using fragments?